# node-rdkafka on macOS: Error: Invalid value "sasl_ssl" for configuration property "security.protocol"

Tags: apache-kafka, ibm-cloud, ibm-eventstreams

I am trying to connect to IBM Event Streams (previously Message Hub) using `node-rdkafka` and seeing the below error

```
/Users/VMac/Documents/VMAC/Code/GIT/kafka-log-simulator/node_modules/node-rdkafka/lib/client.js:54
  this._client = new SubClientType(globalConf, topicConf);
                 ^

Error: Invalid value "sasl_ssl" for configuration property "security.protocol"
    at Producer.Client (/Users/VMac/Documents/VMAC/Code/GIT/kafka-log-simulator/node_modules/node-rdkafka/lib/client.js:54:18)
    at new Producer (/Users/VMac/Documents/VMAC/Code/GIT/kafka-log-simulator/node_modules/node-rdkafka/lib/producer.js:75:10)
    at new Simulator (/Users/VMac/Documents/VMAC/Code/GIT/kafka-log-simulator/dist/Simulator.js:54:29)
    at /Users/VMac/Documents/VMAC/Code/GIT/kafka-log-simulator/dist/index.js:107:33
    at step (/Users/VMac/Documents/VMAC/Code/GIT/kafka-log-simulator/dist/index.js:52:23)
    at Object.next (/Users/VMac/Documents/VMAC/Code/GIT/kafka-log-simulator/dist/index.js:33:53)
    at /Users/VMac/Documents/VMAC/Code/GIT/kafka-log-simulator/dist/index.js:27:71
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at __awaiter (/Users/VMac/Documents/VMAC/Code/GIT/kafka-log-simulator/dist/index.js:23:12)
    at streamMessages (/Users/VMac/Documents/VMAC/Code/GIT/kafka-log-simulator/dist/index.js:102:12)
```

I tried other answers on StackOverflow but no luck. I am trying this on **macOS 10.15.7 (Catalina)**

Comment: Might be a longshot, but have you tried setting the security.protocol property with  `SASL_SSL` (in capital letters)?

Comment: Also check if you have set these [environment variables](https://github.com/Blizzard/node-rdkafka/blob/56c31c4e81f2a042666160338ad65dc4f8f2d87e/README.md#mac-os-high-sierra--mojave) before `npm install`.

Comment: Tried both the options and no luck